# how to add site speed template if there is already .htaccess file present?? Or where to add or should i create new htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to add site speed template if there is already `.htaccess` file present? Or where to add or should I write an entire new `.htaccess`?

I want to add `.htaccess` in my directory for site speed template and there is already a `.htaccess` of wordpress present.

So what should I do? Should I edit in the same or create a new file?

Comment: What is "site speed template"? Please provide more information. Also read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: The "where" question is best answered by: best is in the real http servers host configuration.